# agregar un sonido cuando se inserta algo en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, web

como puedo ejecutar un sonido (beep) en el ordenador cuando tenga en el navegador una web php y cuando se inserta un dato en una tabla en mysql, ejemplo: tengo una web php abierta y llega un mensaje nuevo, como hacer para emitir algún sonido la web que me indique que se ha insertado algo en BD mysql, realizar un where cuando en mysql hay un valor nuevo, emitir un sonido (como llamo a un archivo wav o mp3 y se ejecute en php)

Comment: Hola Ivan, aunque tu pregunta puede ser interesante, puede ser cerrada por ser un tema "demasiado amplío", te recomiendo [edit] tu pregunta y agregar lo que llevas y/o haz intentado

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podria serte util la clase `SWFSound` puedes ver la documentación aquí.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.swfsound.php

Este es un ejemplo que viene en la misma pagina:

```
<?php
$movie = new SWFMovie();
$movie->setRate(1);

$img1 = new SWFBitmap(fopen('./tmp/img1.jpg', 'rb'));
$img2 = new SWFBitmap(fopen('./tmp/img2.jpg', 'rb'));
$img3 = new SWFBitmap(fopen('./tmp/img3.jpg', 'rb'));
$snd1 = new SWFSound(fopen('./tmp/1.wav', 'rb'), SWF_SOUND_22KHZ|SWF_SOUND_16BITS|SWF_SOUND_MONO);
$snd2 = new SWFSound(fopen('./tmp/2.wav', 'rb'), SWF_SOUND_22KHZ|SWF_SOUND_16BITS|SWF_SOUND_MONO);
$snd3 = new SWFSound(fopen('./tmp/3.wav', 'rb'), SWF_SOUND_22KHZ|SWF_SOUND_16BITS|SWF_SOUND_MONO);

$s = $movie->startSound($snd1);
$s->loopcount(1);
$s->loopinpoint(1 * 100);

$i = $movie->add($img1);
$i->setDepth(1);
$movie->nextFrame();

$s = $movie->startSound($snd2);
$s->loopcount(1);
$s->loopinpoint(1 * 100);

$i = $movie->add($img2);
$i->setDepth(2);
$movie->nextFrame();

$s = $movie->startSound($snd3);
$s->loopcount(1);
$s->loopinpoint(1 * 100);

$i = $movie->add($img3);
$i->setDepth(3);
$movie->nextFrame();

$movie->setBackground(0xff, 0xff, 0xff);
$movie->setDimension(130, 97);
$movie->add(new SWFAction("gotoFrame(0); play();"));
$movie->nextFrame();

$movie->save("bw.swf");
```